# Convert a LEFT OUTER JOIN query to Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I can't figure out how to translate an SQL statement into Ecto.

### The Phoenix Setup

```
mix phx.gen.html Location Country countries name
mix phx.gen.html Location FederalState federal_states name
mix phx.gen.html Calendar Day days date_value:date
mix phx.gen.html Calendar Period periods name 
                                         starts_on:date 
                                         ends_on:date
                                         country_id:references:countries
                                         federal_state_id:references:federal_states
mix pix.gen.html Calendar Slot slots day_id:references:days 
                                     period_id:references:periods
```

### The SQL statement

```
SELECT days.date_value, periods.name FROM days 
LEFT OUTER JOIN slots ON (days.id = slots.day_id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN periods ON (slots.period_id = periods.id and 
(periods.country_id = 1 OR 
periods.federal_state_id = 5)) 
WHERE days.date_value >= '2017-01-01' AND 
days.date_value <='2017-12-31' 
ORDER BY days.date_value;
```

Is it possible to replace this SQL statement with an Ecto function?

Comment: The join function accepts an argument which is used to specify what kinda join you need. Except from that, it would be nice to see what you have tried before we do all the work for you.

Comment: I worked through http://learningelixir.joekain.com/none-of-the-associations-in-ecto/ but can't get it work with Ecto.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `left_join` does a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` by default. The rest of the query is straightforward to translate if you use the same alias name for the tables. If you have a `starts_on` and `ends_on` defined as `Date` structs with appropriate values, this should work:

```
query = from(
             days in Day,
             left_join: slots in MehrSchulferien.Calendar.Slot,
             on: days.id == slots.day_id,
             left_join: periods in MehrSchulferien.Calendar.Period,
             on: slots.period_id == periods.id and
                 (periods.country_id == ^federal_state.country_id or
                  periods.federal_state_id == ^federal_state.id),
             where: days.date_value >= ^starts_on and
                    days.date_value <= ^ends_on,
             order_by: days.date_value
            )
```

Comment: @wintermeyer your latest edit to this answer changes the logic AFAICS. I think you should edit your question as well because now the answer will generate a different query than the question and might confuse future readers.

Comment: Done. It makes more sense this way.