# Convert LEFT JOIN query to Ecto

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I have some queries I need migrate to Ecto and for maintainability reasons, I'd rather not just wrap them in a fragment and call it a day.

They have a lot of LEFT JOINs in them and as I understand from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46464547/13528444), a `left_join` in Ecto does a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` by default. I can't seem to figure out how to specify to Ecto that I want a `LEFT INNER JOIN`, which is the default behavior for a `LEFT JOIN` in Postgresql.

To look at a toy example, let's say posts in our database can be either anonymous or they can have a creator. I have a query to get just enough info to make a post preview, but I only want non-anonymous posts to be included:

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.title,
  p.body,
  u.name AS creator_name,
  u.avatar AS creator_avatar,
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.creator_id = u.id;
```

I would translate that into Ecto as:

```
nonanonymous_posts =
  from p in Post,
    left_join: u in User, on: p.creator_id == u.id,
    select: [p.id, p.title, p.body, u.name, u.avatar]
```

and Ecto spits out

```
SELECT
  t0."id",
  t0."title",
  t0."body",
  t1."name" AS creator_name,
  t1."avatar" AS creator_avatar,
FROM "posts" AS t0
LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" as t1 ON t0."creator_id" = t1."id";
```

which will give back anonymous posts as well.

Comment: According to the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-table-expressions.html), the default for a JOIN is INNER, but a LEFT JOIN is implicitly a LEFT OUTER JOIN. There doesn't seem to be such a thing as a LEFT INNER JOIN. 
If you want an INNER JOIN, you can just use `join` (or `inner_join` which is the same).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `LEFT INNER JOIN`. There is only `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` (`OUTER` part is optional, as `LEFT JOIN` **must be** outer join). So what you want is just `:join` or `:inner_join` in your Ecto query.